# I want to unite every piece of this into a connected unified mesh without anything to clean up afterwards

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, object-mode

[image: Here is the clump, each thing here is its own object]

tried bool-union clumps with ctrl J,each one and nothing seems to give me that simple 1 mesh. is there a way to convert this without booling each of the scales?, the bumps are going deep into the center egg like shape.

also tried every mesh->cleanup option and they all dont give me what i want. i just want all these little bumps and center mesh to forget they have anything inside and become a shell of their super imposed shells.

thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: Hi welcome! Probably not. This is a complex model, and by using boolean usually the topology resulting is at least not good. You could try to use this "joined" multi-mesh object as a base to retopologize a new object, but that will be hard too.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is using the Shrinkwrap Modifier, though it might not affect the look, it will most likely radically change your mesh geometry.

First we have an object consisting of multiple meshes:

[image]

Then we make a high resolution (in terms of vertices) sphere around it:

[image]

Then we put a Shrinkwrap Modifier on it. Choose the initial object as your target. Choose "Project" as the Mode. And check the box "Negative". Lastly click the Apply button.

[image]

I have no idea which is which.

[image]

Seems the icosphere was more then enough high rez. You might want to tone it down a little depending on the level of detail of the initial mesh.

[image]